# Pipelines with error handling in Clojure

Tags: validation, clojure, message, pipeline

I'm looking for a smart way to create composable validation and transformation pipelines in Clojure. The aim is to be able to do simple translation and validation of messages using composable steps.

Main requirements:

- Can be **composed functionally**, i.e. pipelines are pure functions
- Can be applied to **regular Clojure data types** (maps, vectors, lists, and nested combinations thereof)
- Can perform **transformations**, e.g. renaming a key in map
- Can perform arbitrary **validations** (e.g. applying a Schema validation to part of a message)
- Can **bail out gracefully** when errors are detected, and return a meaningful error message (*not* just throwing an exception!)

I guess I can write all this, but don't particularly feel like reinventing the wheel today :-)

Dopes anyone know of a tool that can do this, or have a good idea regarding how to construct one in a clever and general way?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a description of monads, but I don't understand those well enough to know if that's actually the case.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. This sounds like a computation in the Either monad.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at Zach Tellman's [Lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina) library. You can create [pipelines](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina/wiki/Pipelines) of functions with error handlers as other useful functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Promenade](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/promenade) (see [documentation](https://cljdoc.org/d/promenade/)), a library I have been working on for elegant error handling and control flow, useful for some of the things described in the question.